# Android Studio Flutter Multiple Child in body

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Basically im trying to add a Textfield where it saves its input so i can insert in the API url like this:

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://v1.motorapi.dk/vehicles/(Value from textfield)'),
       headers: {"X-AUTH-TOKEN": "crt87d9c4jv19tlo3eh7uenxqoprwdpy",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
      });

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

I have added the textfield in the body like this:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;
  TextEditingController nummerpladeController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body:
        Container(
        child: Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: nummerpladeController,
            ),
          ),
        ),

          child: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return new Column( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [ Text("Registreringsnummer: ""${snapshot.data!.registration_number}"),
                  Text("Status: ""${snapshot.data!.status}"),
                  Text("Type: ""${snapshot.data!.type}"),
                  Text("Brug: ""${snapshot.data!.use}"),
                  Text("Første registrerings dato: ""${snapshot.data!.first_registration}"),
                  Text("Vin nummer: ""${snapshot.data!.vin}"),
                  Text("Mærke: ""${snapshot.data!.make}"),
                  Text("Model: ""${snapshot.data!.model}"),
                  Text("Variant: ""${snapshot.data!.variant}"),
                  Text("Model type: ""${snapshot.data!.model_type}"),
                  Text("Farve: ""${snapshot.data!.color}"),
                  Text("Bil type: ""${snapshot.data!.chasis_type}"),
                  Text("Brændstof: ""${snapshot.data!.fuel_type}"),
                  Text("Sidste syn: ""${snapshot.data!.date}"),
                ], );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I get this error: The argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified. Im not sure if i got the container layout correct, but i have tried looking online on how to do it but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The container already has a `child` the :

```dart
TextField(
 controller: nummerpladeController,
)
```

Instead of `Container` try using a `Column` this way :

```dart
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: nummerpladeController,
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
                      future: futureAlbum,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return new Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text("Registreringsnummer: "
                                  "${snapshot.data!.registration_number}"),
                              Text("Status: " "${snapshot.data!.status}"),
                              Text("Type: " "${snapshot.data!.type}"),
                              Text("Brug: " "${snapshot.data!.use}"),
                              Text("Første registrerings dato: "
                                  "${snapshot.data!.first_registration}"),
                              Text("Vin nummer: " "${snapshot.data!.vin}"),
                              Text("Mærke: " "${snapshot.data!.make}"),
                              Text("Model: " "${snapshot.data!.model}"),
                              Text("Variant: " "${snapshot.data!.variant}"),
                              Text("Model type: "
                                  "${snapshot.data!.model_type}"),
                              Text("Farve: " "${snapshot.data!.color}"),
                              Text(
                                  "Bil type: " "${snapshot.data!.chasis_type}"),
                              Text("Brændstof: " "${snapshot.data!.fuel_type}"),
                              Text("Sidste syn: " "${snapshot.data!.date}"),
                            ],
                          );
                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                        }
                        // By default, show a loading spinner.
                        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
```

Comment: the textfield is now showing, but i can't type anything